# shared spring application context across mulitple ears

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, architecture, n-tier-architecture

What do you think about the concept of sharing a spring context across multiple ears?

Let's say i want to share an Interceptor or Filter because i don't want to have 2 instances of the same bean for my 2 ears for the only reason of saving memory.

There are some blogs about sharing contexts across applications but it only refers to sharing context across multiple wars within an ear.

I know that sharing a context across multiple ears is technically possible  (One way could be defining a context at server startup, and then, at webapplication context initialization, inject the server context as it's parent context).

I don't know if its a convenient design approach to share beans across multiple ears or there is some standard way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Related blog about sharing a webapplication context across multiple wars within an ear:
http://blog.springsource.org/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/